# What is the intuition behind converting two inequalities into one modulus inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am given,

$$  1 + \frac{c}{a} + \frac{b}{a} < 0$$

and,

$$ 1 + \frac{c}{a} - \frac{b}{a} < 0 $$

Now, I this is compactified

$$ 1 + \frac{c}{a} + | \frac{b}{a}| < 0$$

Now, this was shown as a 'skip of steps' as a part of solution in a problem I was doing,  but I can't really argue the skip of steps using any thing intuitive/ rigorous.

Comment: This particular skip may not be correct in the limitations here in the question...

Answer (score 2):

You are really asking why:
$$\frac{b}{a}\lt-1-\frac{c}{a}$$
and
$$-\frac{b}{a}\lt-1-\frac{c}{a}$$
taken together are equivalent to:
$$\left|\frac{b}{a}\right|\lt-1-\frac{c}{a}$$
Indeed, for any two real numbers $x,y$ it is true that $x,-x\lt y$ is equivalent to $|x|\lt y$. This is valid because $|x|=\max(x,-x)$:

- On one side, if $|x|\lt y$, then $x,-x\le|x|\lt y$
- On the other side, if $x,-x\lt y$, by noticing that $|x|$  is *one of* $x,-x$, we can conclude that $|x|\lt y$.

Comment: Is my original inequality wrong? I may be doing something stupid but I can't convert from the original thing to what you are doing here

Comment: @DDD4C4U Just move $1$ and $\frac{c}{a}$ to the right side of your inequalities... which changes their sign...